# Jquery validator - no whitespace entries

Tags: javascript, regex

There is a bug on the application where fields can be validated by just adding whitespace.

I tried adding this method - but this is strict on ANY white space at all - which wouldn't work on a field like - company name

```
$.validator.methods.noSpace = function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || (value.indexOf(" ") < 0 && value != "");
};
```

I've tried to use a regex - that could maybe disallow a whitespace entry of any char length.

```
(/^[^ ]*\s/).test(" ")
```

but this would create an error on a company name field with a space

```
(/^[^ ]*\s/).test("Hudsucker Proxy")
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qp82fnth/

Comment: `/^\s+$/.test(value)` or `/^\s*$/.test(value)` will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
/^\s*$/
```

- `^` - start of string.
- `\s*` - Match space characters zero or more time.
- `$` - End of string.

```js
let validate = (inp) =>{
  return !/^\s*$/g.test(inp)
}

console.log(validate('          '))
console.log(validate('company name'))
```

Comment: ok - should it fail if its like ' company name'  -- how strict should it be - ux wise?

Comment: @TheOldCounty did you checked snippet ? it will show false only in case of empty string